# Is there a function such that $f(x+y) = f(xy)$?

Tags: functional-equations

If we define $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, is there a function that fulfills the condition:

$f(x+y) = f(xy)$

for all $x$ and $y$?

For now, let's assume there are no stipulations on continuity and differentiability.

Comment: Any constant function works.

Comment: Constant functions will satisfy this property.

Comment: Taking $y=0$ we see that $f(x)=f(0)$ identically.

Comment: Choosing $y=0$, we have $f(x) = f(0)$ for all $x$

Comment: Only constant functions would work, because $f(x+0)=f(0)$ for all $x$

Comment: Would anything beyond a constant function work? I should have excluded that case.

Comment: I also specified for all x and y in R. These answers do not work for that condition.

Comment: Have you read the comments?  Several people have shown that only constants work.

Comment: @dsmalenb: Just because the function is constant doesn't mean that it doesn't work for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}.$ Let $f(x)=\text{const}\;\forall\,x\in\mathbb{R}.$ This function satisfies all constraints, and as a number of folks have shown in the comments, this is the only kind of solution.

Comment: @projectilemotion, you are correct.

Comment: @dsmalenb I believe the issue is you are concerned that a constant function will not satisfy the conditions, and those who are commenting are glossing over the fact that they do satisfy the conditions. Suppose $f(x)=c$ is a constant function. Then $f(x+y) = f(xy) = c$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Is this the proof your are looking for?

Answer (score 5):

If $y=0$ then $f(x)=f(x+0)=f(0x)=f(0)$, so $f$ is a constant.

Comment: Is your response answering the OP question? OP says: "is there a function that fulfills the condition:...."?

Comment: @NoChance The title question hardly needs an answer, because $f=0$ is certainly such a function. So it makes sense to give an answer which takes into account the comments, too.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I respect your point but I am not convinced.

Comment: The problem here is that the domain of $f$ is not correctly specified in the question.